# Kubernetes cluster integration “Failed to open apk database: Permission denied” while installing Helm Tiller by GitLab

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, openshift, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to configure `Kubernetes` by using `Openshift` origin so I have added Kubernetes cluster configuration then I have tried to install Helm Tiller after that “`gitlab-managed-apps`” namespace created on Openshift, but this error appeared:

> Something went wrong while installing Helm Tiller
>
> ERROR: Unable to lock database: Permission denied ERROR: Failed to
>   open apk database: Permission denied

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DgeL.png)

How do I solve it?

Comment: What is the output of `kubectl -n gitlab-managed-apps get -o yaml pod` while the tiller pod is running? I would expect it will contain `securityContext:` that shows which UID the image is _attempting_ to run as, when it should be running as root to be able to execute `apk` commands

Comment: This is the part of  securityContext in the output:
      securityContext:
        capabilities:
          drop:
          - KILL
          - MKNOD
          - SETGID
          - SETUID
        runAsUser: 1000120000

And this UID is the output of "oc describe project gitlab-managed-apps" command:
Annotations:            openshift.io/sa.scc.mcs=s0:c11,c5
                        openshift.io/sa.scc.supplemental-groups=1000120000/10000
                        openshift.io/sa.scc.uid-range=1000120000/10000

So how can I grant permission for this user?

Comment: _how can I grant permission for this user_ I would just change `runAsUser` to be `0` like normal, since root privileges in a container is not root on the host, but I haven't used OpenShift to know what traps are hiding under that change

Comment: When I changed the value to 0 then this error appears:
Invalidvalue: "s0:c12,c9": mustbes0: c11,
c5spec.containers[0].securityContext.securityContext.runAsUser: Invalidvalue: 0: mustbeintheranges: [1000120000,
1000129999]
Please advise @MatthewLDaniel